# Drawer Menu Shows Gaps

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter. I got a Drawer Menu but there is a little gap between user information side and menu items section.

[image: Gap Photo]

**drawer menu user information side**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserInformation extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserInformation({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
      accountName: Text(
        "KULLANICI ADI",
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
      ),
      accountEmail: Text(
        "email@aspar.com",
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white60),
      ),
      currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
        child: Text(
          "AS",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 40, color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**drawer menu items**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'aboutUs.dart';
import 'mygloves.dart';
import 'contact.dart';

class MenuItems extends StatelessWidget {
  const MenuItems({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: [
        const Divider(thickness: 3, color: Color(0xFF166FC0)),
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            debugPrint("Tapped");
            Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (glovesContext) => MyGloves()));
          },
          child: const ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline_sharp),
            title: Text(
              "Your Gloves",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            ),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.navigate_next_sharp),
          ),
        ),
        const Divider(thickness: 3, color: Color(0xFF0FA9EA)),
        InkWell(
            child: ListTile(
                onTap: () {},
                leading: const Icon(Icons.fiber_new_outlined),
                title: const Text("What's New in Aspar?",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                trailing: const Icon(Icons.navigate_next_sharp))),
        const Divider(thickness: 3, color: Color(0xFF166FC0)),
        InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (newsContext) => const Blog()));
            },
            child: const ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.add_box_outlined),
                title: Text(
                  "About Us",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.navigate_next_sharp))),
        const Divider(thickness: 3, color: Color(0xFF0FA9EA)),
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: const ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.help_outline),
              title: Text(
                "Help",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.navigate_next_sharp)),
        ),
        const Divider(thickness: 3, color: Color(0xFF166FC0)),
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (contactContext) => const Contact()));
          },
          child: const ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.contact_mail_outlined),
              title: Text(
                "Contact",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.navigate_next_sharp)),
        ),
        const Divider(thickness: 3, color: Color(0xFF0FA9EA)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

What should I do to remove that gap between items and user information section?Plus, I added padding zero,if I didn't there'd be larger gap.
Thanks for reply.

Comment: You will need to share the code that creates the `UserAccountsDrawerHeader` Widget. So that we can see if there is something there influencing this spacing. You should also show us how you are putting this all together. The parent widget to the `UserInformation` and the `MenuItems`.

Comment: @João Soares it belongs to flutter source code, I didn't create it

Comment: Can you please share the the link for the specific documentation for this?

Comment: of course https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/UserAccountsDrawerHeader-class.html @João Soares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem, problem caused by "default height" of divider which is invisible in my codes.

I set height same as thickness and gap has gone.

```
children: [
        const Divider(
          thickness: 3,
          color: Color(0xFF166FC0),
          height: 3,
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a few things. However, the DrawerHeader() widget has a default bottom margin and will likely be the cause.

```
DrawerHeader(child: Text('Header'), margin: EdgeInsets.zero),
```

Comment: it didn't work unfortuneatly, gap is still presenting

Answer (score 0):

In your `DrawerHeader` section, Put both `margin` and `padding` into `EdgeInsets.zero`:

```
DrawerHeader(child: ..., margin: EdgeInsets.zero,padding: EdgeInsets.zero),
```

Also, If you want to minimaze the Divider space set the both thickness and height to 3

```
Divider(thickness: 3, height: 3, color: Color(0xFF166FC0))
```

Try various methods and apply the one that suits you.

Comment: it didn't work unfortuneatly, gap is still presenting

Comment: I think the problem is in UserAccountsDrawerHeader , What is the code?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/UserAccountsDrawerHeader-class.html it's default widget